# ASP.NET Which validationgroup caused validation fail

Tags: asp.net, validation, validationgroup

There are 3 validation groups on the page

Group1
Group2
Group3

After validating the groups

```
Page.Validate("Group1");
Page.Validate("Group2");
Page.Validate("Group3");
```

Page.IsValid is false

How can I find out which group caused validation to fail and which ones passed?

Answer (score 2):

Check Page.IsValid after each call.

Comment: `+1` That's the kind of answer everyone knows, but no-one thinks of.

Comment: No. 
If Group1 fails Page.IsValid is always false after checking Group2 and Group3 even if they are valid.
I need to know exactly valid/or not for each group.

Comment: Page.IsValid validates all validators in active validation group so you have 2 options. Either set all validators IsValid property to true, or create empty group and validate it before validating your next group

Answer (score 1):

Why not checking right after calling validate?

Comment: I need to know valid or not for each group but Page.IsValid set to fals after the first validation fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
Page.Validate("Group1");
if (!Page.IsValid)
    return "Group 1 did not validate";

Page.Validate("Group2");
if (!Page.IsValid)
    return "Group 2 did not validate";

Page.Validate("Group3");
if (!Page.IsValid)
    return "Group 3 did not validate";
```